# porque iframe en ios no funciona?

Tags: ios, cordova, intel-xdk

Hola amigos necesito ayuda he creado un app en cordova y e incrustado en una parte un iframe con una web, pero esta no se visualiza el iframe queda vacio, y la consola no me muestra ningun error. Alguno de ustedes sabe porque puee estar ocurriendo esto?

Comment: Tal vez necesitas configurarlo en tu **Entitlement.plist** en iOS como un **associated domain**.

Answer (score 1):

¿Porque no mejor usas el 'empaquetador' de cordova?

Desde terminal accede al directorio de tu proyecto
y escribe lo siguiente para añadir la plataforma iOS

> cordova platform add ios

Gener el paquete para iOS

> cordova build ios

Prueba en el simulador

> cordova emulate ios

Para abrir el proyecto generado por cordova para XCODE ve a la ruta siguiente

> PATH_DE_PROYECTO/platforms/ios

Comment: esto no es una respuesta a lo que han preguntado

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que configurar las URLs a las que quieres que tu app pueda navegar, eso se hace con la etiqueta allow-navigation en el config.xml

`<allow-navigation href="http://tupagina.com/*" />`

Si quieres permitir la navegacion a cualquier pagina entonces usa un *

`<allow-navigation href="*" />`